# SQL - multiple date time aggregations within single query

Tags: sql, teradata, data-manipulation

I have a SQL database of customer actions, a customer is defined by a UniqueId and an action is given a date and time of action timestamp. A user can have more than one action on any one day as so:

```
UniqueID | actionDate | actionTime |
   1       17-01-18     13:01
   1       17-01-18     13:15
   2       17-01-18     13:15
   1       18-01-18     12:56
```

I want to understand multiple things from the database ideally in a single query.

1. The first is how many times has each uniqueId preformed an action over a given time period (day, week, month) so for the example above there would be a count of 2 for id1 for 17-01-18, a count of 1 for 18-01-18 and assuming they are the only two actions that week a count of 3 for id 1 for that week.
2. On days that have more than one action (17-01-18 in the above example) I would want to understand the distribution of actions across the day and more importantly the number of actions that occurred within a time frame of an hour. In this case id want to understand that 2 actions occurred between 13:00 - 14:00 for id 1 but the other 23 hours had 0 actions.

The end goal would be to have a time series that looks back over three months and be able to view monthly, weekly and importantly daily / intra-daily counts of actions for each unique ID.

Desired result may look something like this:

```
ID | M1W1D1H1|M1W1D1H2|->|M1W1D1H13|->|M1W1D2H12|
   1   0         0            2             1
   2   0         0            1             0
```

M=Month, W=Week, D=Day, H=Hour. AC = ActionCount

So the above shows that on month 1, week 1, day 1, hour 1, id1 had no actions. The first action was on M1W1D1H13, in which time they had two actions. There next action was on D2 of W1, M1. Could then aggregate up to get the respective, weekly, daily monthly actions. The result will be fairly sparse with many 0 action.

Any help and guidance appreciated.

Comment: Edit your question and provide desired results.  As written, the question is too broad.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - My bad, its Teradata

Comment: Three months result in approx. 92*24 = 2208 hours = 2208 columns in your result set. Besides the fact that Teradata only supports 2048 columns this should be done in the representation layer. To get the base count per hour you can use group by `UniqueID, actionDate, extract(hour from actionTime)`

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question you have an id with a date and time details in a normalized data structure.  You, however, want to denormalize this data so that you have only one line per id aggregated at the conditions you desire.

To do this you could use a simple group by and nest your aggregations into case statements qualifying them for the column range you desire.  If you can not hard code your time slices and need that to be dynamic that may be possible but I would need more information about your requirements.  You can also nest case statments into case statements and use derived tables to further enable more complex rules.

So, using your example...

```
sel
  UniqueID 
, sum(
  case when actionDate between <someDate> and <someDate> then 1
  end) as evnt_cnt_in_range01
, count(distinct(
  case when actionDate between <someDate> and <someDate> then actionDate
  end)) as uniq_dates_in_range01
, min(
  case when actionDate between <someDate> and <someDate> then actionTime
  end) as earliest_action_in_range01
, max(
  case when actionDate between <someDate> and <someDate> then actionTime
  end) as latest_action_in_range01
, max(
  case when actionDate between <someDate> and <someDate> then
    CASE WHEN actionTime > '12:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END -- I flip caps to keeps nests straight
  end) as cnt_after_noon_action_range1
FROM <sometable>
group by 1
```